# Multiply a number with 0.01

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to multiply a number which is like these `00000000001099` with `0.01` and then convert into two decimal places for e.g., `10.99` after multiplication in a derived column in SSIS package.

Right now I am using these expression `(dt_numeric,2,2)((DT_CY)((dt_wstr,14)PRICE) * 0.01)` but it is failing.

I get the column price with value `00000000001099` from a flat file after conversion I need to place the value back to a flat file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your string is 14 long you cannot use DT_I4 - it'll just figure out that this is very wrong and give you the error about potential loss of data. You could edit the error and ignore possible truncations, but a better way is to use a datatype that can hold your number

Your Derivation should look like this:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,X,2)((DT_NUMERIC,X+2,2)([InputColumn]))*0.01)
```

In your example

```
(DT_NUMERIC,14,2)(((DT_NUMERIC,16,2)([PRICE]))*0.01)
```

By using the extra step with x+2,2 makes you able to hold 99999999999999 into the numeric, then divide by 100 (or multiply with 0.01) and cast back to the minimum possible numeric (x,2) - you might want to use a bigger standardized numeric type - look at MSDN/BOL to see the storage requirements for each of them, and just pick the biggest type taking the same amount of bytes as your requirement.

Comment: (This will also strip leading zeroes)

Comment: I am using your exp still i am getting the error as Type cast [Derived Column [96]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (96)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "test" (1723)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
No truncation error now..Any suggestion?

Comment: Somewhere in your data is invalid input, meaning something that doesn't translate to a number. Make a path with error and redirect error rows on the derived column step and hook up a data viewer to look at the lines where conversion fails.

Comment: exactly i got it i used the data viewer to fing there are some null in the incoming file thanks for your help

Comment: You can wrap it all in a !ISNULL([PRICE]) ? EXPRESSION : (DT_NUMERIC,14,2)0.00 to make it process NULL as zero values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
(DT_DECIMAL, 2 )(DT_WSTR, 20 )((DT_I4)@[User::Cost] * 0.01)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but still i am getting the type cast error and one more thing the cost value is coming from the flat file where i used Ragged right to extract the field from 21 to 35 position (i.e..,14 length) i am not storing in a variable any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, the variable was what I was using to test the expression, apologies for any confusion!  Can you post the error message you are getting?

Comment: [Derived Column [96]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.

Comment: [Derived Column [96]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (96)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "Derived Column 1" (1600)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (96) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column Input" (97). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Sorry it restricting the space to post entire message in one comment.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Can you confirm what the data type of the Price column is coming in as?

Comment: From the flat file source in the advanced editor tab i can see the Price column properties as: Name:Price,InputColumnWidth:14,DataType:string[DT_STR],outputcolumnwidth:14,textqualified:false and other properties as disabled.

Comment: @revelator,
Any suggestions or idea about it,i can do like these

(substring(PRICE,11,1) == "0"?(dt_wstr,1)SUBSTRING(PRICE,12,1) :         (dt_wstr,2)SUBSTRING(PRICE,11,2))+ "." + ((dt_wstr,2)SUBSTRING(PRICE,13,2))
it works but i need a generic answer? any help

Comment: Do you get an error if you use part of the expression, such as (DT_WSTR, 20 )((DT_I4)Price * 0.01)?  I'm assuming that the conversion to integer is the root of this issue.

Comment: Yes i am getting the error Type cast if i use the above exp (DT_WSTR, 20 )((DT_I4)Price * 0.01).

Comment: [Derived Column [96]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (96)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "Price" (1723)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Is your Derived column overwriting an existing column with a different datatype?  If so, create a new column instead.

Comment: Source and destination are both Flat files i need to evaluate the expression on the incoming field and write the result to the destination i am not overwriting column i am creating a new column itself in the derived column transformation but getting the above errors i need to get rid of leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

While the value 00000000001099 is a number, it cannot be represented this way in a numeric datatype.  The leading zeros will be stripped.  Because you are showing this number this way, I must presume the number is stored in a string datatype.  In the dataflow before your derived column I would recommend the use of the "Data Conversion" component.  Convert the string to a numeric type.  In the downstream derived column component perform the mathematical multiplcation operation to get the decimal point in the correct place.

Comment: thanks for reply,but i am get the following error [Data Conversion [1691]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "PRICE" (18) to column "PriceDC" (1699).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".